# having trouble with the date function in php5 MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to submit a customers date of birth into a database, and the result is "0000-00-00" ....not sure what I am doing wrong..

Here is the code:

```
    <td>Date of Birth:</td>
  <td><label for="dob"></label>
  <input type="text" name="dob" id="dob" /><?php $dob = date("m/d/Y", strtotime($result['dob'])); ?></td>
```

Thanks!

Comment: what do you get if you leave out the strtotime? what's in $result['dob']? Also, it looks like you're setting $dob to a value, but not doing anything with it.

Comment: That's not the code that inserts anything into a database. Changing your code that displays what's already there won't fix a problem with saving the wrong date.

Comment: ehhh what? there is nothing in this code that has anything to do with databases. also, did you mean to put that date into that input's value? it seems you have printed it next to the input instead.

Comment: if you dont input the timestamp into MySQL properly it will default to "0000-00-00 00:00:00" you need to check what your inputting and make sure its the correct format

Answer (score 2):

Check you `<input>` tag ... it's missing a `value` attribute.